# How to get a sum of the value which I get in the if condition

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sum

First of all, I am new in this programming area, so I don't know how to do this?

I have a database table `video_master`  in that I have `ID, REC_ID, VIDEO_DATE, VIDEO_COUNT, IS_REDIM` fields.
Now I want a count of that amount. I use if and get an amount as video, but now I don't know how to take the sum of that amount, i.e. total amount.  Here, I am providing what I have done.

```
<?php
// If user not logged in then show login message
   if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) 
   {
?>
    <div class="message">
        To access this page, you must be logged.<br />
        <a href="connexion.php">Log in</a>
    </div>
<?php
   }
   else
   {
      //Video count values of the database
      if(isset($_REQUEST['date1']) && isset($_REQUEST['date2']))
      {
        $dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select video_date,video_count from video_master where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and video_date >= "' . $_REQUEST['date1'] . '" and video_date <= "' . $_REQUEST['date2'] . '"');
      }
      else
      {
        $dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select id,video_date,video_count,is_redim from video_master where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"');
      }

      if(mysqli_num_rows($dnn)>0)
      {
?>
         <table>
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Video Count</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Is Redim ?</th>
                </tr>
           </thead>
     <?php
            while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($dnn))
            {
              //$video_date = date("Y-m-d","d-m-Y",$rowData['video_date']);
                $video_date = $rowData['video_date'];
                $video_count = $rowData['video_count'];
     ?>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $rowData['id']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php print($video_date); ?></td>
                 <td><?php print($video_count); ?></td>
                 <td><?php //echo $rowData['video_count'];
                 if($rowData['video_count'] < 250){
                          $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0;
                          echo $amount1;            
                 } 
                 else{
                        if($rowData['video_count'] <= 500){
                        $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.25;
                        echo $amount1;            
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                          if($rowData['video_count'] <= 750){
                                $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.50;
                                 echo $amount1;            
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1000){
                                $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.75;
                                echo $amount1;            
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1250){
                                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1;
                                    echo $amount1;            
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                 if($rowData['video_count'] < 1500){
                                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1.50;
                                    echo $amount1;            
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                 }        

                              }        
                            }
                           }                      
                        } 
                 } 
               ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $rowData['is_redim'];  ?></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
      } 
        ?>
        <?php
    }
        ?>
```

I get a `$amount` as a video, but now I want to calculate the total of that `$amount`. `amount` field is not in the database. I get the amount from video_count.

UPDATED PROBLEM

```
<?php

     $total_amt = 0; 

    // If user not logged in then show login message
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {

        ?><div class="message">
            To access this page, you must be logged.<br />
            <a href="connexion.php">Log in</a>
        </div><?php
    }
    else{

        //Video count values of the database
        if(isset($_REQUEST['date1']) && isset($_REQUEST['date2'])){
            $dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select video_date,video_count from video_master where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and video_date >= "' . $_REQUEST['date1'] . '" and video_date <= "' . $_REQUEST['date2'] . '"');
        }
        else{
            $dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select id,video_date,video_count,is_redim from video_master where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"');

         }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($dnn)>0)
        {
            ?><table>
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Video Count</th>

                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Is Redim ?</th>
                </tr></thead><?php

                while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($dnn)){
                    //$video_date = date("Y-m-d","d-m-Y",$rowData['video_date']);
                    $video_date = $rowData['video_date'];
                    $video_count = $rowData['video_count'];

                    ?><tbody><tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rowData['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php print($video_date); ?></td>
                        <td><?php print($video_count); ?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $rowData['video_count'];

                            if($rowData['video_count'] < 250){
                  $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0;
                  echo $amount1;            
        } 
        else{
                    if($rowData['video_count'] <= 500){
                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.25;
                    echo $amount1;            
                    } else                                {
                        if($rowData['video_count'] <= 750){
                        $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.50;
                        echo $amount1;            
                        } else                                    {
                            if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1000){
                            $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.75;
                            echo $amount1;            
                            } else                                        {
                                    if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1250){
                                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1;
                                    echo $amount1;            
                                    } else
                                    {

                                        if($rowData['video_count'] < 1500){
                                        $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1.50;
                                        echo $amount1; 

                                        } else
                                        {                                                                


                                        }                                        
                                    }                                                              
                            }
                        }
                    } 
            } 
$total_amt += $amount1;

                    echo $total_amt;

                         ?></td>
                         <td><?php echo $rowData['is_redim'];  ?></td>
                    </tr></tbody><?php
                }
            ?></table><?php
        }   
        ?>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Code that uses input from the browser and sends it unfiltered as a command to sql is essentially an open invitation for attackers to use SQL injection and gain control of your server.

Comment: sir actually i am learning this things and i get your suggestion and keep that in mind.

Comment: @swa66 8 sir actually i don't send the amount in database i just echo because user can get how he earn from watching videos.

Comment: This code: `mysqli_query($conn, 'select `[...]`' . $_REQUEST['date1'] `[...] is the problem: $_REQUEST will contain the POST or GET data straight from the browser into the sql command.   Nothing stops the attacker from terminating the SELECT and doing other things as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
<?php

        // If user not logged in then show login message
        if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {

            ?><div class="message">
                To access this page, you must be logged.<br />
                <a href="connexion.php">Log in</a>
            </div><?php
        }
        else{

//Video count values of the database
if(isset($_REQUEST['date1']) && isset($_REQUEST['date2'])){
$dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select video_date,video_count from video_master     where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and video_date >= "' .     $_REQUEST['date1'] . '" and video_date <= "' . $_REQUEST['date2'] . '"');
}
else{ 
$dnn = mysqli_query($conn, 'select id,video_date,video_count,is_redim from video_master where  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"');
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($dnn)>0)
{
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Video Count</th>
<th>Total Amount</th>
<th>Is Redim ?</th>
</tr></thead><?php
while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($dnn)){
//$video_date = date("Y-m-d","d-m-Y",$rowData['video_date']);
$video_date = $rowData['video_date'];
$video_count = $rowData['video_count'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rowData['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php print($video_date); ?></td>
<td><?php print($video_count); ?></td>
<td><?php //echo $rowData['video_count'];
$total_amt=0;
if($rowData['video_count'] < 250){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

} 
else{
if($rowData['video_count'] <= 500){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.25;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

}
else
{
if($rowData['video_count'] <= 750){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.50;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

}
else
{
if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1000){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.75;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

} else
{
if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1250){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

} else
{
if($rowData['video_count'] < 1500){
$amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1.50;
$total_amt = $total_amt + $amount1;

} else
{
}        
}        
}
}                      
} 
} 
?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $rowData['is_redim'];  ?></td>
</tr></tbody><?php }
  echo $total_amt;  ?></table><?php
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In each row, you have to add the current amount to previous amount.

May be try this.

```
$total_amt = 0;// declare outside the loop.

$total_amt += $amount1;// inside the condition where you are echoing the amount or just outside the main if else block.
```

After your loop ends,

```
<?php echo $total_amt; ?>// will echo the total amount.


if($rowData['video_count'] < 250){
       $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0;
       echo $amount1;            
}  else{
         ...
         ...               
} 

 $total_amt += $amount1;// keep here
```

**EDIT**

One more final thing you have to do is,

```
if($rowData['video_count'] < 1500){
     $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1.50;
     echo $amount1;            
 } else {
     $amount1 = 0;// declare the variable here... last if else() in side main else
 }
```

Comment: sorry sir but i didn't get it.  i put $total_amt += $amount1; &  echo $total_amt; at the end of the loop and the $total_amt = 0; above all condition but i get the sum but in all amount cell i get the amount of that.

Comment: i got the sum sir but i don't know the where i gone a put it because i get all the value. i have "100,0,100,250"  and now i have "100100,0100,100200, 250450,"

Comment: sir i past the $total_amt = 0; right form the top of if(isset) statement and put other two code after the if condition of the amount logic.  actually i don't know where to put it correctly

Comment: sir i got Undefined variable: amount1 on the $total_amt += $amount1; line

Comment: also if you dint want to do that, see the edit part of my answer.

Comment: no sir but i get the amount two time and in last amount cell i get total amount.

Comment: where have you kept the code?? at last or at each place where you are echoing the amount??

Comment: i edit it and put what i done sir.. kindly say where i been mistaken  and thanks for your response sir ..

Comment: you r getting undefined variable error?? if so declare `$amount = 0` outside the loop at the top where you have declared `$total_amt`

Comment: yes sir..  i got all the sum with the original amount like if i have 354,100,100 then i got  354354, 100454,100545

Comment: Thank You very much to give your valuable suggestion thank you very very much !!! @Niranjan N Raju

Answer (score 0):

Final The code which work for me.

```
         <?php



            // $totalamount1 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(video_count) as total From video_master Where is_redim="N" AND rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"' ));


                $amount_count = mysqli_query($conn, 'select video_count from video_master where is_redim="N" AND  rec_id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"');

                 $total_amtt=0;
                 //$amount = 0;

                if(mysqli_num_rows($amount_count)>0)
            {
                while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($amount_count))
                {


                    // $amount = 0;

                                            if($rowData['video_count'] < 250){
                                  $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0;
                                  //echo $amount1;
                                  $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;
                                   // echo $total_amtt;             
                        } 
                        else{
                                    if($rowData['video_count'] <= 500){
                                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.25;
                                    //echo $amount1;            
                                    $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;
                                   // echo $total_amtt;  
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        if($rowData['video_count'] <= 750){
                                        $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.50;
                                        //echo $amount1;            
                                        $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;
                                    //echo $total_amtt;  
                                        } else
                                        {
                                            if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1000){
                                            $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*0.75;
                                            //echo $amount1;            
                                            $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;
                                   // echo $total_amtt;  
                                            } else
                                            {
                                                    if($rowData['video_count'] <= 1250){
                                                    $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1;
                                                    //echo $amount1;            
                                                    $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;
                                    //echo $total_amtt;  
                                                    } else
                                                    {

                                                        if($rowData['video_count'] < 1500){
                                                        $amount1 = $rowData['video_count']*1.50;
                                                        //echo $amount1; 
                                                        $total_amtt = $total_amtt + $amount1;


                                                        } else
                                                        {
                                                               //$amount1 = 0;      


                                                        }  



                                                    }



                                            }


                                        }                      



                                    } 



                            } 

                }
               echo $total_amtt;
            }


            ?>
```